# What should you do if you accidentally talk between Al Netilas Yadayim and Hamotzi?

Tags: blessing, netilat-yadayim-washing, speech-talking, hefsek-interruption, hamotzi-beracha

Assuming one has the minhag not to speak between netilas yadayim and hamotzi...What should one do if one accidentally speaks during this time?

Should one wash again? With or without a blessing?
 --Or should one just go straight to HaMotzi?

If the third, is there any kind of (immediate) tikkun one can do?

...I'm wondering because it just happened to me.

Related: [Hefsek between netilat yadayim and hamotzi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36026/hefsek-between-netilat-yadayim-and-hamotzi)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43603

Comment: @msh210 Hmm yeah. Although I think my question is better (a lot clearer)

Comment: ...Although his encompasses more interesting things

Comment: One thing you should probably _not_ do is stop and ask a question on Mi Yodeya :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even according to the custom of avoiding interrupting between washing and the blessing of *HaMotzi*, one need not wash again if one spoke or otherwise interrupted as long as the person remained mindful to keep their hands clean during the interim ([*Mishna B'rura* 166:6](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A1%D7%95), [English translation](http://books.google.com/books?id=lIyGmAZUXxgC&pg=PA163#v=onepage&q&f=false)):

> דע דעיקר דין תכיפה המוזכר בסימן זה הוא רק מצוה לכתחלה אבל בדיעבד אפילו שהה הרבה או הפסיק בינתים אין צריך לחזור וליטול ידיו כל שלא הסיח דעתו בינתים משמירת ידיו

Translation:

> Know that the essence of the law of immediacy that is mentioned in this section of the *Shulchan Aruch* is only for the ideal (*l'chatchila*) way to perform the *mitzva*. However, after the fact, even if he waited a lot or interrupted, he does not need to go back and wash his hands again so long as his attention did not lapse from guarding his hands in the meanwhile.

Comment: Do you know if it would be permissible to wash again? (without a blessing)

Comment: @sah Doing unnecessary things before hamotzi is generally discouraged

Comment: @SAH I wonder if washing again might specifically be a problem by retroactively rendering the original washing as not for the purpose of the meal (and the original recitation of *al n'tilas yadayim* might not be able to apply to the second washing due to the interruption). Even so, there are some opinions that reciting *al n'tilas yadayim* is mandated for dirty hands even if you are not going to have a meal, so that could be a mitigating factor if someone went and washed a second time (as the first blessing would not be in vain).